# Order from data.frame on ggplot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have data frame:

```
values <- c("a", "d", "b", "c", "e", "f")
n <- c(1463, 159, 54, 52, 52, 220)
frequency <- c(0.7315, 0.0795, 0.027, 0.026, 0.026, 0.11)
tmp <- as.data.frame(cbind(values, n, frequency))
```

And I would like to to draw geom_bar of this data (x = values, y = frequency) but data of the plot should be ordered like it is in data frame (a,d,b,c,e,f). Unfortunately ggplot automaticly order column values and I get (a,b,c,d,e,f). Code for plot:

```
ggplot(data=tmp, aes(x=values, y=frequency)) +
  geom_bar(fill="#003366", stat="identity") +
  labs(title = "...", x = "values", y = "Frequency")
```

What I should change in plot function to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The factor's levels can be re-ordered using the `factor` function.

```
values <- c("a", "d", "b", "c", "e", "f")
n <- c(1463, 159, 54, 52, 52, 220)
frequency <- c(0.7315, 0.0795, 0.027, 0.026, 0.026, 0.11)
tmp <- as.data.frame(cbind(values, n, frequency))
# reorder using factor
tmp$values = factor(tmp$values, levels = values)

ggplot(data=tmp, aes(x=values, y=frequency)) +
  geom_bar(fill="#003366", stat="identity") +
  labs(title = "...", x = "values", y = "Frequency")
```